# Scheduling in Cron tab for regular interval

Tags: unix, cron, cron-task

Hi I have 2 jobs where 2nd job needs to run 30 min after 1st job.

I am using crontab -e to setup cron job

```
1st job     0 * * * * /home/hadoop/datapull.sh
2nd job  /home/hadoop/loaddata.sh
```

I have scheduled my 1st job (datapull.sh) like above which will run evrey hour.

Subsequently my 2nd job needs to run after 30 min of completion of 1st job.

```
Lets say my 1st job runs 1PM,2PM,3PM,4PM so on and my second job should be around 1.30PM,2.30PM,3.30PM,4.30PM .
```

How can I schedule my 2nd job to in cron tab to setup like this.
Ned help for setting up cron tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second job:

```
30 * * * *  /home/hadoop/loaddata.sh
```

This will run your cronjob, f.e. on 0:30, 1:30, 2:30, 3:30, ...

**This is how a cronjob is setup in general:**

```
 # * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

**What does Asterisk (*) mean**

The asterisk indicates that the cron expression matches for all values of the field. E.g., using an asterisk in the 4th field (month) indicates every month.

---

**Sidenote**

Other special characters in cronjobs

**Slash ( / )**

Slashes describe increments of ranges. For example 3-59/15 in the 1st field (minutes) indicate the third minute of the hour and every 15 minutes thereafter. The form "*/..." is equivalent to the form "first-last/...", that is, an increment over the largest possible range of the field.

**Comma ( , )**

Commas are used to separate items of a list. For example, using "MON,WED,FRI" in the 5th field (day of week) means Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays.

**Hyphen ( - )**

Hyphens define ranges. For example, 2000-2010 indicates every year between 2000 and 2010 AD, inclusive.

**Percent ( % )**

Percent-signs (%) in the command, unless escaped with backslash (), are changed into newline characters, and all data after the first % are sent to the command as standard input.

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thanks Michael..Just one Query...Just thinking as per the rule 1st field is minute.So will it start executing in every 30 min.

Comment: No, that means the 30s minute of every hour (because the second field for hour is *). If it should run every 30 minutes, you'll need to put it like */30 which will let it run every 30 minutes

Comment: This will run depending upon system time.?

Comment: Yes exactly like this

Answer (score 2):

the first job should be start at minute 0 from each hour like
1st job     0 * * * * /home/hadoop/datapull.sh
as you wrote
but second job must be start at minute 30 like :
2nd job   30 * * * * /home/hadoop/loaddata.sh 

best regards